# Does anyone know algorithm of MKMapPointForCoordinate function in ObjectiveC MapKit

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

MapKit has function MKMapPointForCoordinate, It accept lat lng as argument and return point x,y.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/index.html

lat = 59.90738808515509
lng = 10.724523067474365

if we pass above lat, lng then function return

x = 142214284, y = 78089986

I check with lag lng wot UTM  but it gives different result
http://www.latlong.net/lat-long-utm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MKMapPointForCoordinate` doesn't return UTM Coordinates.
Coordinates refer to a position on the earth (a pseudo-sphere), but sometimes you need to do calculation refering to a 2D map (much simpler) and then convert again to coordinates. This is the goal of the conversion.
So, the `MKMapPoint` struct returned by `MKMapPointForCoordinate` is a 2D representation of the coordinates, but it doesn't match any standard known.

At this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKMapPoint

in the `MKMapPoint` documentation, you can read:

> The actual units of a map point are tied to the underlying units used
>   to draw the contents of an MKMapView, but you should never need to
>   worry about these units directly. You use map points primarily to
>   simplify computations that would be complex to do using coordinate
>   values on a curved surface.

**EDIT**

for Coordinates-UTM Conversion in a previous project I used [this Open Source Code](https://github.com/palmerc/GeodeticUTMConverter)